# Jquery script not working in master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This code works fine in .aspx page no issues. but if i use master page then nothing works fine here,

i tried placing the JQuery script in Master page,  even then nothing is  working. is there any thing setting need  to be done here.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
     $('#<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>').change(function() 
    {    
     if($(this).is(':checked')) 
     {       
      $("#divControlGroup").css("display", "block");   
      $("#ddlcounty option:first").attr("selected", true); 
      } 
     else 
        { 
    $("#divControlGroup").css("display", "none"); 
     } 
        })
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked="false" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="divControlGroup" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcounty" runat="server">
                      <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">India</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">US</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">UK</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

any help would be appreicated

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe the errors you're seeing? Is it possible that the path to the jQuery file `"jquery-1.6.2.min.js"` is incorrect from the Master page?

Comment: You gave jquery a relative path. Try absolute path.

Comment: what happens if you start your script with `if (typeof jQuery === "undefined"){alert("jQuery not loaded");};`

Answer (score 4):

Change your MasterPage script reference to use `ResolveUrl()` and put your script inside the `ContentPlaceHolder` being used:

```
 <script src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>

 //script related to the specific page needing ClientID refs
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" Runat="Server" >
    <script>....</script>
</asp:content>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using master page (and content placeholders), stuff like:
`$("#divControlGroup")` will not work. You need to use the clientID, like you do earlier, in your code.

The content placeholder, gets added to the ID, which is why it doesn't match.